# LibGDX camera position shifted on movement

Tags: libgdx, box2d, camera, perspective, jbox2d

I'm programming a game with LibGDX and Box2D and I want my camera to follow my player. But as I zoom in (because Box2Ds metric system, using camera.zoom = x) the camera is shifted when the player moves (the camera follows the player):

[image: Shifted Position]
*Shifted View*

[image: Normal Position]
*Normal View*

That only happens when the player moves, so there can't be a problem with the coordinates. My Question is how to remove this shifting as the player moves.

Here's some of my code:

*Render Loop (excerpt):*

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //set the camera position to player's position
    cam.position.set(player_body.getWorldCenter().x, player_body.getWorldCenter().y, 0);
    cam.update();

    world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 6, 2);
    world.clearForces();

    handleInput();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.05f, .05f, .05f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    debugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined);

}
```

*Make the player move:*

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
    player_body.setLinearVelocity(transX, transY);
    player.setMoving(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer. You need to set the camera's position directly after calling world.step() and then it works without shifting.

```
world.step(...);
camera.position.set(...);
camera.update();
```

([Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694594/libgdx-camera-position-shifted-on-movement?noredirect=1#comment43918767_27694594))